# Oracle INSERT ALL CURRVAL error

Tags: oracle, insert

I have 3 tables, TBL_A, TBL_B and TBL_C.

TBL_A has an ID (lets call it ID_A) thats PK of A, and FK of B and C. ID_A have a trigger with an autoincrement before insert.

The problem:

I need to make an Insert All that looks kinda like this

```
INSERT ALL
INTO TBL_A(FIELD1, FIELD2) VALUES('VALUE1', 'VALUE2')--like i said before, the trigger autoinsert the id with the NEXTVAL in MY_SEQ sequence.
INTO TBL_B(ID_A, FIELD) VALUES (MY_SEQ.CURRVAL, 'VALUE')
INTO TBL_C(ID_A, FIELD) VALUE (MY_SEQ.CURRVAL, 'VALUE')
SELECT * FROM DUAL
```

But, for some reason it says that sequence MY_SEQ.CURRVAL is not yet defined in this session . What can i do to solve it? Cant find a way to do it.

I need to keep the trigger because that insert can be huge.

PLZ help me and srry about my english btw ^^

Comment: Why do you need a single `INSERT ALL` statement?  Why wouldn't three separate `INSERT` statements in a single PL/SQL block (a stored procedure or an anonymous PL/SQL block) be sufficient?

Comment: Because theres like 12000 registers per/day to insert, separate inserts would take a lot more time than a few insert all.

Comment: Why would 12000 anonymous PL/SQL blocks take more time than 12000 `INSERT ALL` statements?  Or is your actual code getting the 12000 rows from a single query rather than doing a `select * from dual` as the example that you posted is?  Even if you're inserting data in the slowest, least efficient manner possible, 12,000 inserts a day is nothing.

Answer (score 0):

```sql
INSERT ALL
INTO TBL_A(ID, FIELD1, FIELD2) VALUES(id, val1, val2)
INTO TBL_B(ID_A, FIELD) VALUES(id, val)
INTO TBL_C(ID_A, FIELD) VALUES(id, val)
SELECT
    MY_SEQ.NEXTVAL as id, 'VALUE' as val, 'VALUE1' val1, 'VALUE2' val2
FROM DUAL
```

Comment: Is the trigger mandatory? Huge insert would work faster without a trigger. You can have the .nextval in your select statement.

Answer (score 0):

This have worked fine for me:

```
 INSERT ALL INTO TBL_A(FIELD1, FIELD2) VALUES('VALUE1', 'VALUE2')
 INTO TBL_B(ID_A, FIELD) VALUES (MY_SEQ.CURRVAL, 'VALUE')
 INTO TBL_C(ID_A, FIELD) VALUES (MY_SEQ.CURRVAL, 'VALUE')
 SELECT * FROM DUAL;
```

Indeed this really works when I call at least once MY_SEQ.NEXTVAL. In all other runs this is working fine without call NEXTVAL. I think the sequence must be properly initialized

Answer (score 0):

You can't use a sequence in the subquery of a multi-table insert and you shouldn't use it in the values clause like that because it can give unpredictable results.

You might consider populating the data into a global temporary table with the sequence and then doing your multitable insert using the global temporary table.  Of course this would require modifying the trigger.